# Generate 10 Random Integers storing them in an Array and then calling a Method to display the Array

Tags: java, arrays, random

so i need to generate 10 random integers in the range 1-20 but i have to store them in an array
called numbers. Then I have to call a method called displayArray which displays the contents of the
array and for the assignment i have to use a for loop to traverse the array.

The method header for the displayArray method is:

```
public static void displayArray(int[] array)
```

This is what I have done

```
public class RandomIntegers {

    static int numbers = 0;

    public static void displayArray(int[] array) {
         System.out.println(numbers + "Numbers Generated");
    }

}//end class
```

and

```
public class Random_Integers{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RandomIntegers[] numbers = new RandomIntegers[10];

        //Generates 10 Random Numbers in the range 1 -20
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
          numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 20);

            RandomIntegers Numbers = new RandomIntegers();

            numbers[i] = Numbers;

        }//end for loop

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers Numbers = numbers[i];       

            Numbers[i].displayArray;        
            System.out.println();

        }//end for loop
  }//end main method
}//end class
```

An error appears on the lines

Type mismatch cannot convert from int to RnadomIntegers

```
numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
```

numbers cannot be resolved to a type

```
numbers Numbers = numbers[i];
```

Syntax error enter 'AssignmentOperator Expression' to complete expression

```
Numbers[i].displayArray;
```

I realize I need to assign an instance of the RandomIntegers class to the slot in the array to fix the first problem but i don't know how, could someone show me how do to so

and i don't know how to fix the other 2 problems i'm only learning how to use java so could someone please guide me in the right direction

Comment: Why do you have two classes in the first place? All you need in your main method is `int[] numbers = generateRandomNumbers(); displayArray(numbers);`, and then define these two static methods in the same class. Each of those 2 methods should use a loop: one to fill the array, and the other to display each element of the array. Don't make things more complex than they need to be, since you've not grasped types and classes yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only have to use a single for loop - like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] numbers = new int[10];       
    //Generates 10 Random Numbers in the range 1 -20
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*20 + 1);
    }//end for loop
    System.out.println("Numbers Generated: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

Comment: For future refrence, you will also have to ```import java.util.Arrays;```

Answer (score 2):

To generate a random *integer*, you're best off using this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(20)+1;
```

The `rand.nextInt(20)` call will give a random number from 0 to 19, so adding 1 makes it from 1 to 20.

In practice, you don't need to create a new `Random()` every time; you'd put this

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

at the beginning of your loop, and then

```
numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(20)+1;
```

inside it.

Since you've got several errors, I'd suggest you start again, write your code bit by bit, and check at each stage that it compiles and does what you want. For instance, start by printing a single random number out, and check that that works.

Answer (score 0):

you have created an array of type RandomIntegers use this it will work `int[] numbers = new int[10];`
there is no problem with the code

Answer (score 0):

From Java 8 onwards you can use following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new Random().ints(1, 21).limit(10).toArray();
    System.out.println("Numbers generated: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

Output:

```
Numbers generated: [4, 14, 8, 14, 19, 16, 13, 2, 3, 1]
```

Here in `ints(randomNumberOrigin, randomNumberBound)` randomNumberOrigin is inclusive and randomNumberBound is exclusive. So you might want to increase randomNumberBound number by 1.